# Такие() как — знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация, как, сравнительный-оборот

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужны ли запятые в следующих предложениях?

Такие вот(,) как она(,) только тем и занимаются, что сплетничают.
Такие(,) как он(,) позорят наше ведомство.
Такие люди(,) как этот герой(,) достойны восхищения.

Answer (score 4):

**Запятая ставится**, если если в основной части предложения имеется указательное слово (так, такой, тот, столь):

Такие вот, как она,  только тем и занимаются,что сплетничают. Такие, как он, позорят наше ведомство. Такие люди, как этот герой, достойны восхищения.

**Но:** Люди, **такие как этот герой**, достойны восхищения. Указательное слово включено в оборот.

[Розенталь: § 42. Сравнительный оборот](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147)

Примеры:

Но откуда такие берутся, вот **такие**, **как он**, тихие, настырные и дурные? [Ю. О. Домбровский. Факультет ненужных вещей, часть 1 (1978)]

Многие великие люди, **такие как** Гете, Байрон, Стендаль, Бальзак и Ганс-Христиан Андерсен, жили некогда здесь в близлежащих домах. [Андрей Ростовский. Русский синдикат (2000)